# Quadratic Recurrences

Tags: recurrence-relations, hyperbolic-functions

is there any way to solve 'simple' recurrences like $a_0=2$, $a_{n+1}=(2a_n-1)^2$ or even $a_0=1$, $a_{n+1}=(2a_n+1)^2$ ? Any help much welcomed !
Regards, Knud

Comment: Depends what you mean by "solve". It isn't difficult to see that both those sequences diverge to +infinity, which can be seen by finding the first few terms of the sequence.

Comment: Well, solving means 'knowing' some expression for the $a_i$. And yes, the first case is easy, essentially giving the square-root by an infinite product. Finally I'm interested in some 'integral representation', not of the sequence, but the function defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote $b_n = 2a_n -1$, then
$$b_0 = 3$$
$$b_{n+1} = 2b_n^2 -1$$

We seek $x$ satisfying $b_0 = \text{cosh}(x) := \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$   then
$$x = \text{arcosh}(3) = \ln(3+2\sqrt{2})=2\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)$$
Now, it is easy to prove that  $b_n = \text{cosh}(2^nx)$, indeed
$$b_{n+1} = 2\left(\frac{e^{2^n x} +e^{-2^n x}}{2}  \right)^2 -1 =\frac{e^{2^{n+1} x} +e^{-2^{n+1} x}}{2}  = \text{cosh}(2^{n+1}x)$$

Conclusion:

$$a_n =\frac{\text{cosh}(2^{n+1}\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)) +1}{2} $$

Comment: I've to check, not now :) What about the 'permanent' instead of the 'determinant' case ? Thanks for replying ! :)

Comment: $\text{arcosh}(3) = 3+2\sqrt{2}$. Wow, that was some nap I took. When I nodded off $\text{arcosh}(3)$ was equal to $\color{blue}{\ln}(3+2\sqrt{2})$. You may want to stay alert and check.

Comment: @OscarLanzi You're right, it's a typo. I corrected it.

Comment: @Knud What do you mean by 'permanent' and 'determinant"?

Comment: oh ... well ... any way to communicate ?

Comment: It's about the structure of the resulting infinite linear systems

Comment: www.probits.de, you get my full contact information

Comment: And, obviously - but still any comment highly welcomed - the 'permanent' case was the 2nd one ;)

Comment: convergence is even faster than in the 1st case, which makes the solution not easier ;)

Comment: The fundamental difference between the 'determinant' and 'permanent' is, that the permanent does not know about '-'

Comment: It just counts, always 'plus'

Comment: @Knud the second sequence, if you make a change of variable $b_n = a_n +1$, then you will have the following sequence $$b_0 = 2$$ $$b_{n+1} = (2b_n-1)^2 +\color{red}{1}$$
The new sequence is like the first sequence that they all begin at $a_0 = b_0 = 2$. However, the sequence $(b_n)_n$ have one additional 1 unit each step. 
$$$$I don't think there are closed form expression for $(b_n)_n$ (so, the second sequence).